# Calling App Maker server scripts from outside of App Maker UI

Tags: google-app-maker

App Maker Guide (server script section) mentions that " It is important to note any function you define in a server script is open to all users of your application, even if you do not expose it in the UI."
How can I call an app maker server script outside of UI?

Comment: At this time I don't believe that there is an App Maker API to call a server script outside of the app maker environment. Depending on what you are trying to accomplish with your server script you could possibly look at Apps Script Service as an Executable, but that would still not allow you to access any services within App Maker.

Comment: In addition to what Markus said, Please provide your use case so we can provide a possible way out to achieve the result.

Comment: As REST API is not available I was looking for a work around. I am using InvoiceOcean for invoicing in my company and I wrote a webhook to capture relevant events (customer/invoice creation,change, deletion etc). I was looking for an easiest way for webhook and app maker to talk (without a need of moving SQL to custom one).  If I could call an App Maker function from my apps script it would solve the issue in straightforward way.

Comment: I don't know of any way to have app maker accept a webhook callback.  Your only option may very well be to move to a custom SQL instance and have some other host accept the callback to modify your database.

Comment: I wonder if this is something Google could put on the product roadmap. The product is designed for non engineers and indeed it gives powerful and easy to understand ways to work with data. Having to step outside that to manage webhooks separately doesn't allow simple enough workflow integration.

Comment: I agree that it would be a useful feature but webhooks are a difficult concept for beginners to understand.  I would imagine such a feature would allow you to define some callback URL from within your app and then accept requests and manipulate data based on the request contents.  Not very different than the programming you would do in any other language or framework.