# How to refresh appmaker table on change in calendar event of a calendar(dynamic) on current day?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-app-maker

I have created a app in appmaker. In that there is a table which should get refreshed (i.e a particular appscript function (client-side function)should run to refresh the table) whenever any change in calendar events of a particular calendar on the current day takes place.
How to set such type of trigger?

I did some R&D and found that there is something called watch function in calendar API but I'm not sure if it is useful for my problem.

By table I am referring to appmaker table widget.

If setting the appscript calendar trigger, Client refresh may be a problem. Because in my ui above the table  there is a dropdown to select the calendarId which refreshes the table by running the below code:

```
       var calendarId=app.pages.Events.descendants.Dropdown1.value;
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function() {
         app.datasources.Events.load();
       }).getTodayEvents(calendarId); 

        /* In getTodayEvents() current day events of the calendarId are 
       fetched from that calendar and stored in DB */
```

Can this happen from server side through trigger?

Also trigger should be based on the calendarId currently selected in dropdown.
So the calendarId needs to be dynamic in the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

A calendar watch requires an webhook that will process some logic when there is an event modification(create, update, delete). Unfortunately, App Maker does not yet support such a thing and here is a discussion about it [Calling App Maker server scripts from outside of App Maker UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731481/calling-app-maker-server-scripts-from-outside-of-app-maker-ui). On top of that, you would require to interact with the client side rather than the server, so definitely not.

In this case, the best thing you can do is set an interval that will refresh the ui every certain seconds or minutes.

```
setInterval(function(){
    app.datasources.myDatasource.load();
},60000); //60 seconds
```

A more advanced way of approaching this would be using firebase and cloud functions. I have implemented firebase on some projects with reliable results. You can read more about firebase and cloud functions on the below links:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup
- https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/

Comment: As @Dimu below says, What's stopping him from just creating a calendar trigger using `ScriptApp.createTrigger()`?

Comment: @TheMaster can you please kindly explain how am I supposed to refresh the client side by calling a server script using this kind of trigger? I will greatly appreciate that! Please take into account this is an App Maker project.

Comment: I expect the client side to be always kept in sync with the sql.  Calendar  change initiates trigger > Triggers server  function > function updates sql table. Even if the client isn't in sync,  The question states `In that there is a table which should get refreshed`. I don't think it refers to the ui. `a particular appscript function should run to refresh the table`. I believe it's a server apps script function. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @TheMaster in my experience with App Maker, if you want to see any new changes on the database, you need to refresh the ui either manually or programmatically. The problem is that a server script cannot trigger an action that will force the client to refresh, therefore I believe the approach suggested by **@DimuDesigns** is not feasible in this scenario. However, since OP is assuming that a server script can perform such a task, this seems a bit confusing. I know for a fact that is not possible... unless I misunderstood the term **table**.

Comment: @Morfinismo By table I assumed that the OP is referring to a MySQL table served up (from the backend) by Cloud SQL **not** the "table" widget that's a part of App Makers drag-n-drop user interface.

Comment: HI, After seeing the comments here, I have added few more details in my question to make it more clear. Please see the updated question.

Comment: @Morfin Guess you were right. Can you explain how/why firebase/cloud functions make a difference. As I see, The only way from client side is by polling from inside the client as you've shown using `setInterval`. Are you suggesting polling the firebase?

Comment: @TheMaster I am not suggesting to poll from firebase. Firebase already integrates something similar to a watch system in their realtime databases. However, that is too complicated to explain so I'd definitely go with the `setInterval()` solution.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be applicable to your use case but for non-app-maker script projects I'd do the following:

- Go to your GSuite Developer Hub via https://script.google.com/home/my
- Select the desired script project
- On the right is a box titled "Project Details", click the menu icon (top-right) and select "Triggers"
- Click the "Add trigger" button (bottom-right)
- In the pop-up modal select the function you wish to run, and set the event source to "Calendar".

Note that this "Calendar" trigger can only detect updates to your primary calendar. Changes to secondary calendars you create will not be tracked.